# CSS fluid height box

Tags: css

I wanna stretch this box incase If it doesn`t fit on background area how can I do that ?

There is a plus button that puts another div on this page after 4 div boxes they start going out of the box how can I fix it ?

http://tinyurl.com/7ewkvrh

Comment: make height:100% and most of the time it solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many `</div>` tags. Re-count them more carefully to fix the problem. Check the difference between "second" and "fourth", for example. You'll see you have one `</div>` on the "second", but two of them on the "fourth".

Answer (score -1):

`#content` and `.service-item` should have: `overflow: hidden;` It will then automatically expand when needed.

Comment: Can the -1 guy please explain what's wrong with this answer if the solution works?

Comment: I just did - see the comment.

Comment: Thanks. But even if he fixes the html I still think he should do the overflow stuff.

Comment: I'm under the impression that `overflow: hidden` hides the overflow. Is this not the case?

Comment: Only if you give the box a fixed height, which you didn't. With `overflow:hidden` you can let a div 'grow' if the inner div's are all floated. you can also add a div with `clear:both` after the floated divs.